# help with BitConverter!

Tags: c#, c++, bitconverter

I cannot get the BitConverter class to work. I get the error 'BitConverter' undeclared (first use this function). I have tried putting 'using System;' at the top of my code because I saw that in some examples online, but it then tells me that 'System' has not been declared. What am i missing? A #include file?

Comment: Did you mean C++ for the tag?

Comment: I don't think so...is this class not available in c?

Comment: Since when there are classes in C?! :)

Answer (score 0):

BitConverter is a CLI class, If you don't mean the CLI class then you've lost me completely and can ignore the rest of this answer. #include is c++. Is this managed c++? Please clarify and re-tag the question as approriate.

If it's Managed C++ you use

```
using namespace System
```

to include namespaces instead of C#´s

```
using System
```